# Ayuda con una SQL Query

Tags: sql, select

En una base de datos SQL, tengo una tabla de referencias de piezas con cantidades, ubicaciones de stock y fecha de entrada del stock. Necesito hacer una consulta sobre para saber de que ubicaciones de stock sacar un número determinado de piezas. Priorizo sobre ubicaciones que tengan la fecha de entrada mas antigua y que tengan el numero de piezas que yo quiero sacar. El problema viene cuando en una ubicación no tengo bastantes para poder coger y tendría que sacar de otra. No se me ocurre como plantearlo, para que el resultado de la query sean las columnas de donde coger.

Ahora mismo el código que tengo es:

```
SELECT 
  [Ctd],[Ubicacion] 
  FROM [dbo].[Ubicaciones]
 WHERE HoraFecha = (select MIN(HoraFecha) from [dbo].[Ubicaciones]) AND Ctd >= "CantidadExtraer"
```

La tabla que tengo seria del siguiente tipo:

```
CODIGO     Ctd       Ubicacion     FechaHora
5555        2           PK01        17/11/17
5555        2           PK02        18/11/17
5555        3           PK03        19/11/17
5555        3           PK04        20/11/17
5555        4           PK05        21/11/17
```

Con la consulta que tengo hecha en caso de querer sacar CantidadExtraer = 4, el resultado seria 4 PK05. 
En la siguiente orden si quiero volver a extraer 4, el resultado deberia de ser:
2 PK01, 2 PK02.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: panki, para lo que necesitas no te sirve solo un query, necesitas todo un procedimiento completo.. SQL no es el lenguaje para lo que queres (por lo menos no puro)

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal, tienes dos "lógicas" para recuperar las ubicaciones:

1. Si la cantidad a extraer es menor a la de alguna ubicación, obtenemos la ubicación más antigua
2. Si en ninguna ubicación llegamos a cubrir la cantidad requerida hay que recuperar las ubicaciones más antiguas hasta completar la cantidad.

El siguiente código es una prueba de concepto de una solución a tu problema:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ubicaciones (
    CODIGO      INT,
    Ctd         INT,
    Ubicacion   CHAR(4),
    FechaHora   DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Ubicaciones(CODIGO, Ctd, Ubicacion, FechaHora)
    VALUES  (5555, 2, 'PK01',  '2017/11/17'),
        (5555, 2, 'PK02',  '2017/11/18'),
        (5555, 3, 'PK03',  '2017/11/19'),
        (5555, 3, 'PK04',  '2017/11/20'),
        (5555, 4, 'PK05',  '2017/11/21')

CREATE TABLE #UbicacionesSolicitud (
    CODIGO      INT,
    Ubicacion   CHAR(4),
    Ctd         INT,
    FechaHora   DATETIME,
    Acumulado   INT
)

DECLARE @Cantidad   INT

-- CANTIDAD A BUSCAR ---------
SELECT @Cantidad = 5
------------------------------

-- 1. Hay alguna ubicación que cubre totalmente el pedido?
INSERT INTO #UbicacionesSolicitud (CODIGO, Ubicacion, Ctd, FechaHora, Acumulado)
SELECT  TOP 1 CODIGO, Ubicacion, Ctd, FechaHora, Ctd
    FROM #Ubicaciones
    WHERE Ctd >= @Cantidad
    ORDER BY FechaHora

-- 2. Si no hay casos 1, entonces listamos las ubicaciones necesarias para cubrir la cantidad
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #UbicacionesSolicitud)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #UbicacionesSolicitud (CODIGO, Ubicacion, Ctd, FechaHora, Acumulado)
    SELECT  U1.CODIGO,
        U1.Ubicacion, 
        U1.Ctd, 
        U1.FechaHora,
        SUM(ISNULL(U2.Ctd,0))
        FROM #Ubicaciones U1
        LEFT JOIN #Ubicaciones U2
            ON U2.CODIGO = U1.CODIGO
            AND U2.FechaHora <= U1.FechaHora
        GROUP BY U1.CODIGO, 
            U1.Ubicacion,
            U1.Ctd, 
            U1.FechaHora
        ORDER BY U1.FechaHora

    DELETE  #UbicacionesSolicitud
        FROM #UbicacionesSolicitud U
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   TOP 1 CODIGO, Ubicacion, Acumulado
                FROM #UbicacionesSolicitud
                WHERE Acumulado >= @Cantidad
                ORDER BY Acumulado
            ) H
            ON H.CODIGO = U.CODIGO
        WHERE U.Acumulado > H.Acumulado
END

-- Salida final
SELECT  *
    FROM #UbicacionesSolicitud


DROP TABLE #UbicacionesSolicitud
DROP TABLE #Ubicaciones
```

#### Explicación

- En primer lugar creamos una table `#Ubicaciones` con los datos de tu ejemplo y otra tabla `#UbicacionesSolicitud` que albergará la lista de ubicaciones a las que habría que hacer el pedido en función de la cantidad.
- La primer consulta, es para verificar si hay alguna ubicación con stock suficiente, en cuyo caso traemos únicamente la más antigua
- La segunda parte es un poco más compleja, pero básicamente lo que se hace es un un Acumulador de cantidades desde la ubicación más antigua a la más nueva
- Luego obtenemos la primer ubicación cuyo acumulador es igual o mayor a  `@Cantidad` y borramos a partir de esta ubicación las que siguen.
- Al finalizar simplemente listamos `#UbicacionesSolicitud` dónde tendremos las ubicaciones a solicitar.

**Nota importante:** Esta consulta está definida para trabajar de a un producto a la vez tal como has indicado en tu ejemplo.